# Determine by code if object was created in static context

Tags: java, android, reference

Is it possible in Java to check by code if an object has been created in a static context?

Background: I want to decide for a given object if I store it with a weak or a strong reference depending on it's type (static class / object created in a static context -> strong reference, regular object -> weak reference). I need to keep the reference within a possibly long-living request which is possibly the only object keeping a reference to the referent. As I'm programming for Android these objects are possibly activities and I don't want to keep those activities around just because there is still a possibly outdated request around - hence the need for weak references in this case. But if the request was made by a static class or in a static context I want to keep the static class around (those classes usually don't take much memory in opposite to whole activities).

Hopefully this requirements don't sound too crude. ;) We plan to exchange the activity based communication in the future in favor of a single communication service, but for the time being a simple solution with weak references (and strong references just where absolutely necessary) will do, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: No.

You can imagine the new keyword as a static method call (like a factory method). No context is passed to the constructor, except its parameters (for non-static inner classes the compiler magically adds the parent object reference as a parameter. Thats invisible in the source code).

The easy way to do this is add a parameter to the constructor and let the caller explicitly decide what he wants.

Comment: That's exactly how I finally ended up doing it. Will wait another day if there are alternative solutions and then mark this answer as accepted.